How do I apply multiple selection criteria to a single node?
I'm looking to select the centre point of a face. I've been able to identify using the below that if I filter the selection to the 'dirt' material, and then select the first (0 index) point it is the one I am looking for. However, I have realised I don't actually want the 'points to vertices' conversion node that I am using as the entry point for the second 'selection' filter. Is there a node I can use that will allow me to filter the points from the 'mesh to points' node or will I need to do something silly like convert to vertices and then convert back to points? I also considered some sort of 'add' for the selection inputs, but I do need them to chain, i.e. select dirt first, THEN select the first index.
Long time viewer first time poster, I apologise if my question does not make sense or is very basic. Thank you for your time!

This is what my node tree looks like now

And this is what I'm after. Or is this essentially what I already have?
EDIT (2): Removed the extra about the end goal as I think this was confusing some people and added an image of what I want the nodes to look like
EDIT (3): Thank you Markus! The 'Delete Geometry' node was exactly what I was looking for!
I needed to use the 'selection' component twice in a row- I wanted to select the 0 index OF the selection of the material, like so:


tbh i don't get what you want. Where is the dirt in your picture? Maybe i am too blind/silly, but i don't see it. And so i don't know where the leaves should rotate to. Maybe a "before" and "after" image with "after" is what you want to achieve would help? but i am 99% sure that you don't have to make these conversions and that there are easier/better solutions.

Sorry, I do not know what you are actually asking. What kind of multiple criteria? And you say you want to select the center point of that certain face and you have identified it. Well what is left to do then? And even without selecting the material, if this is a single geometry (since all geometry comes from the Group Input), each point has its individual index so the only thing you need to find is the index of that specific point.

If you want to get only the first point (index = 0) then simply delete all other points:

Keep in mind the "Greater Than" node is not needed here, as indices are never negative, and any non-zero integer will implicitly convert to TRUE boolean.
